# f(x)= $ \int\frac{3x^2+4}{(x^3+4x)^2}dx $

Tags: calculus

f(x)= $ \int\frac{3x^2+4}{(x^3+4x)^2}dx $

My answer is [image]

Why is my answer wrong? My Professor has a hard time explaining why. Thanks for your help before hand.

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: Your answer (and solution) is correct.

Comment: He did not mark it as correct.

Comment: well it's written very badly.

Comment: The red marks indicate some places where you could improve how you wrote your process, but the result is correct.

Comment: @ADG Written badly as in my penmanship?

Comment: I think it is because you forgot the $du$ on your second integral.

Comment: Oh. If he supplied the red marks, then you should have written the "du". Aside from this, I see nothing wrong with what you did. The work could have been organized a bit better...

Comment: @Cetshwayo in an unorganized manner.

Comment: You say your professor has a hard time explaining why. Can you write down (approximatelly) what he said was wrong?

Comment: He gave me this quiz back and told me to correct my mistakes. He speaks several languages; however, his English can be hard to understand.

Comment: @Cetshwayo Then I don't know what you're asking. The mistakes you made are clearly shown with the pink/red pen.

Comment: @5xum: There are even mistakes that aren't indicated by the red pen. For example, "$3x+4\text{dx}$" makes **no sense**, just as "$(3x+4)y$" is **not** the same as "$3x+4y$".

Answer (score 4):

I presume the *he* in question is a real person of flesh and bone. I advise you to go talk to *him*, not to *us*. *he* may be able to explain what your mistake was.

I assume the red marks are not yours and were added later. In that case, it is very unclear to me where you get the equation

$$\frac{du}{3x^2+4} = \frac{3x^2+4}{3x^2+4}dx$$

There is no method seen in your solution. No path of where you started and where you finished, and, more importantly, there is no sign that this is not just written from some other solution without understanding.